# uicollection view within a tableview cell getting ERROR: Index out of range, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an array (4 items) of type `Venue` each contains an array (2 items) of `imgURLs` String and I am getting an **ERROR: Index out of range** at the following line of my `collectionView` `cellForItemAt`. I am trying to display the images for each Venue in a collectionView within the tableview cell.

```
let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[collectionView.tag]
```

`cellForItemAt` function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VenueListingCellImage", for: indexPath) as! VenueListingCellImage

    let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[collectionView.tag]

    let imgURL = URL(string: urlString)

    cell.configureCell(url: imgURL!)

    return cell
}
```

EDIT: `numberOfItemsInSection` function

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs.count

    }
```

Comment: Show numberOfItemsInSection method code

Comment: i've edited my question to include numberOfItemsInSection function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[collectionView.tag]
```

To

```
let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[indexPath.item]
```

Comment: this has worked, but this has created an issue whereby when I select a Venue to view details and segue back to the tableview, it is reloaded and the images now dont line up with the Venue?

Answer (score 1):

In your code replace:

```
  let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[collectionView.tag]
```

with:

```
  let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[indexPath.item]
```

Answer (score 1):

CollectionView `cellForItemAt indexPath` iterates your array through `indexPath`, so to access each item you should use `indexPath.item`

Here is the problem, you should use,

```
let urlString = filteredVenueArray[collectionView.tag].imgURLs[indexPath.item]
```